# Replace blank value with a default value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the below query which return blank values for the column property_value :

```
select target_name,target_type,property_name,property_value
from oracle_properties
where target_name like 'DY01EPI%' and property_name like 'DataGuardStatus'
```

output from sql developer:

[image]

How can i get a default value like 'primary' if the the row in Property_value is blank.
I have tried using `NVL(property_value,'Primary')` and `COALESCE(property_value,'Primary')` which didnt give expected result.Please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: `coalesce()`should do the work. Otherwise it means that your string is neither `null`, nor empty.

Comment: @GMB neither null, nor empty...thats a new thing i learnt.What would be the solution in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the value is not `NULL`.  You might use regular expressions for this:

```
select target_name, target_type, property_name,
       (case when regexp_like(property_value, '[a-zA-Z0-9]') then property_value
             else 'primary'
        end) as property_value
from oracle_properties
where target_name like 'DY01EPI%' and
      property_name like 'DataGuardStatus'
```

Comment: Thanks..this worked as expected.Can you explain the regexp condition for my understanding

Comment: @vivek . . . It is just checking for an alphanumeric character in the field.

Answer (score 1):

the property_value column might have either NULL value or whitespaces for all occupied spaces within the columns's value, e.g. blank-padded, then you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function with `'[[:space:]]'` pattern :

```
SELECT target_name, target_type, property_name, 
       NVL( REGEXP_REPLACE(property_value,'[[:space:]]'), 'Primary') AS property_value
  FROM oracle_properties
 WHERE target_name like 'DY01EPI%'
   AND property_name like 'DataGuardStatus';
```

in order to escape all of those blank characters.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=39812ec87e9331489b4a2aee24b69d5d)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

How about using case

```
select target_name,target_type,property_name, 
case when property_value is null then 'PRIMARY' else property_value as property_value
from oracle_properties 
where target_name like 'DY01EPI%' and property_name like 'DataGuardStatus'
```

This will replace the null values with PRIMARY as per your requirement else it will show the actual property value.

Comment: Above query throws error:ORA-00905: missing keyword
                                     00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: @vivek try my updated answer. I have added brackets and a name (called as alias)

Comment: That's strange. This should work. Try trial and error method. try to remove just the brackets and rest remains the same.